# $\mathbb{C^*}/\mathbb{S}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R^*}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've already shown that $\phi(\alpha)=|\alpha|$ is an onto homomorphism. I'm just not sure that the $\ker(\phi)=\mathbb{S}$

I do know that $\mathbb{S}=\{\alpha \in \mathbb{C} :|\alpha|=1\}$ though which would give me the identity in $\mathbb{R}$. Should I be looking at something that looks like $\{\alpha \in \mathbb{C^*} :|\alpha|=1\}$ instead? Is that set $\mathbb{S^*}$?

Comment: What does the notation $X^\ast$ stand for?  Do you mean the set $X\setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: @Hayden Usually it denotes the multiplicative group of units in a ring. In this case, because $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are fields, it stands for the multiplicative group of nonzero complex/real numbers.

Comment: That's what I figured, but didn't know if it was somehow a much more advanced question dealing with hyperreal and hypercomplex numbers...

Answer (score 3):

Note that $|0|=0$, so certainly $\{\alpha\in \Bbb C:|\alpha|=1\}=\{\alpha\in\Bbb C^\times:|\alpha|=1\}$

Comment: Stole the words out of my mouth :)